# Why is the reason of React's better performance over direct DOM manipulation using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, performance, dom

I have doubts related with DOM manipulating in reference to comparison
between React Virtual DOM and JQuery direct DOM manipulation.
Let's say we want to update one DOM node:

A)by using React.js :

1.React creates Virtual DOM (in-memory,'javascript-made' representation of real DOM ), let's call it VD1

2. render()

3.React crates a new one Virtual DOM instance, let's call it VD2

4.React compares VD1 and VD2 and detects that they differ at one node element

5.React locates that place and 'injects' the change by intact only the "changing' place without rebuilding whole real DOM from the root to the top of the DOM tree

B)The same but using JQuery:

1.We made change by directly manipulate the real DOM via JQuery
    command

2. Browser detects change so it goes through the whole (real)DOM tree and looking for the changed place

   3.After finds it applies the change and rebuild the DOM to present user a new version of page

If I understand it correctly, this is the main reason of letting go JQuery and direct DOM manipulation in favour of Virtual DOMs and better performance in general of React?

Comment: check this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/52555662/3555775

Answer (score 0):

React uses the Virtual DOM, so it has everything stored in memory the way it wants it so it can be easily searched to get the elements it wants. It makes the modifications it needs to, then runs a difference algorithm so it only has to update the things that are absolutely necessary. With jQuery, the DOM manipulation happens all inline, so doesn't have a virtual version and has to parse the actual DOM, which is much less efficient than parsing a version stored in the Virtual DOM.